# display only one div in modal popup dialog box in angular from templateurl html file

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog

I have 2 div in my template urls and from ts file i need to call only particular div but when i give `dialog.open`, both the div are getting displayed in popup dialog box.

When the page is loaded, i want only A div should be loaded.

When i click openDialog , B Div should be displayed
But both the div is getting displayed.

passHist.component.html

### First div

```
<div id="A">
  <li>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Password History</button>
  </li>
</div>
```

### Second div

```
<div id="B">
  <div>
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Password History</h1>
  </div>
  some content inside
</div>
```

## TS File

## passHist.component.ts

```
openDialog(ispassButton, ispassContent): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PassHistComponent, {
      width: "1000px"
    });
  }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: '.passHist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['.passHist.component.css']
})
```

Please help and provide suggestions how to do this
Thanks

Both A and B div is getting displayed in popup dialog
but inside only B div should be displayed.

Comment: Minor formatting changes and text changes

Answer (score 0):

When opening `PassHistComponent` in a dialog, you can provide custom `data` in the `MatDialogConfig`. Depending on that `data`, you can show or hide your `div`.

In your specific case, the `data` type could look as follows:

```
interface DialogData {
    showA: boolean;
    showB: boolean;
}
```

Your component must accept the `data` attribute.

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PassHistComponent>, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData ) {        
}
```

The dialog could be opened as follows:

```
openDialog(ispassButton, ispassContent ): void {
    const dialogData: DialogData = { showA: false; showB: true };
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PassHistComponent, 
        { data: dialogData,  width: '1000px' });
    ...
}
```

In your template.

```
<div id="A" [hidden]="!data.showA">
   ...
</div>
```

For further explanations, please read [Sharing data with the Dialog component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-)

Comment: Thank you so much.Your answer perfectly suits and its working fine.Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers